# How to update a row based on other rows in pandas in an efficient way

Tags: python, pandas

I want to update values on a pandas df row based on other rows.

I have a dataframe with patients, all the vaccines they need to get, a column that indicates if they have already applied it or not, and a "status" column, that is "Ok" if they applied the vaccine, or "Missing" if they don't.

The problem is that there are vaccines that are equivalent. In the example below, vaccines B and C are equivalent. So if the patient applied vaccine B, he shouldn't apply vaccine C. Therefore, the correct status in this case is "Ok" for vaccine B and "Applied equivalent vaccine" for vaccine C.

The dataframe is over 2 million rows, so I need an effient way to build the "desired_status" column.

Any ideas how to do that? Thanks!

| patient | vaccine | applied? | status | desired_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 | Ok | Ok |
| 1 | B | 1 | Ok | Ok |
| 1 | C | 0 | Missing | Applied equivalent vaccine |
| 2 | A | 0 | Missing | Missing |
| 2 | B | 0 | Missing | Applied equivalent vaccine |
| 2 | C | 1 | Ok | Ok |
| 3 | A | 1 | Ok | Ok |
| 3 | B | 0 | Missing | Missing |
| 3 | C | 0 | Missing | Missing |

PS: Equivalent vaccines are not necessarily in adjacent rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dictionary to map equivalents, then use `groupby`+`agg` and `numpy.select`:

```
eq_vaccines = {'B': 'BC', 'C': 'BC'}

vac = df['vaccine'].map(eq_vaccines).combine_first(df['vaccine'])
applied_any = df.groupby(['patient', vac])['applied?'].transform('max').eq(1)

import numpy as np
df['status'] = np.select([df['applied?'].eq(1), applied_any],
                         ['Ok', 'Applied equivalent vaccine'], 'Missing')
```

output:

```
   patient vaccine  applied?                      status
0        1       A         1                          Ok
1        1       B         1                          Ok
2        1       C         0  Applied equivalent vaccine
3        2       A         0                     Missing
4        2       B         0  Applied equivalent vaccine
5        2       C         1                          Ok
6        3       A         1                          Ok
7        3       B         0                     Missing
8        3       C         0                     Missing
```

###### table with intermediates for clarity

```
   patient vaccine  applied?                      status  vac  applied_any
0        1       A         1                          Ok    A            1
1        1       B         1                          Ok   BC            1
2        1       C         0  Applied equivalent vaccine   BC            1
3        2       A         0                     Missing    A            0
4        2       B         0  Applied equivalent vaccine   BC            1
5        2       C         1                          Ok   BC            1
6        3       A         1                          Ok    A            1
7        3       B         0                     Missing   BC            0
8        3       C         0                     Missing   BC            0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's exactly what I needed.

One question - you are using this ".eq(1)" in the end to transform the series to a True/False boolean, right? How exactly does this work? Which pandas function is this calling?

Comment: @Bruno yes `eq(1)` compares to 1 and returns a Series of booleans (the method is [`eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) and is the same as doing `series == 1`), I could have used `astype(bool)`. I did this step because `numpy.select` won't do the automatic conversion to booleans.

Comment: Ah, ok! So eq is a build-in method. I thought you were using the "eq" Series that you created with .map and .combine_first. Thanks for the answer and the clarification.

Comment: @Bruno I admit this could be confusing ;) I'll update the names

Answer (score 0):

```
def function1(dd:pd.DataFrame):
    dd1=dd.iloc[1:,[3]]
    if dd1.squeeze().eq("Ok").any():
        dd.loc[dd1.query("status == 'Missing'").index,'status']='Applied-equivalent-vaccine'
    return dd['status']

df1.groupby('patient',group_keys=False).apply(function1)
```

out：

```
0                            Ok
1                            Ok
2    Applied-equivalent-vaccine
3                       Missing
4    Applied-equivalent-vaccine
5                            Ok
6                            Ok
7                       Missing
8                       Missing
```